# RabbitVCS GUI does not appear

Tags: linux, version-control

I installed RabbitVCS on my linux box which went without a hitch.  Now I'm having trouble running the thing, I want to bring up the GUI.  Naturally I tried rabbitvcs from the command line, then rabbitvcs SVN but no luck ( see output below ). I get usage info, but that didn't seem to help me much.  How can I run it in GUI mode ?

--------------------------------------
flipper@matrix ~ $ rabbitvcs
Usage: rabbitvcs module [path1] [path2] ...

### Available Modules

SVN:
    about, add, annotate, applypatch, branch, browser, changes, checkmods, 
    checkout, cleanup, commit, createpatch, create, delete, diff, editconflicts,
    export, ignore, import, lock, log, merge, properties, open, relocate, rename, 
    markresolved, revert, settings, switch, unlock, update, updateto

Git:
    about, add, annotate, applybranch, branches, changes, checkout, clean, 
    clone, commit, createpatch, create, delete, diff, editconflicts, export, 
    ignore, log, merge, open, push, rename, remotes, reset, revert, settings, 
    tags, update

For module specific help type: rabbitvcs  -h

flipper@matrix ~ $ rabbitvcs SVN
flipper@matrix ~ $ rabbitvcs SVN -h
flipper@matrix ~ $

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you can see here, [RabbitVCS is actually a Nautilus plugin](http://wiki.rabbitvcs.org/wiki/about/screenshots). Try taking a look at your working copy through Nautilus.

It has no separate GUI.

By the way, I actually tried using it for a while, but I found it somewhat slow and clumsy. I switched to using the SVN and git console commands.

I later found that [meld](http://meld.sourceforge.net/) actually provides me with a *very* nice visual diff. It understands SVN and git, but you'll need the very latest version to make the git diff work just right.

Comment: Ah, yes I see what you mean. It works much like Tortoise on windows.  I will make sure to update my meld, Thanks.

Comment: I went to RabbitVCS from this thread only to realize its a nautilus extension. So, I did a little more snooping around and found [meld](http://meldmerge.org/)

Comment: Also, don't forget to restart!  Rabbitvcs did not appear on my Redhat linux until after a restart.

Comment: There is a Nemo extension too, if you're on Linux Mint it could help.

Comment: RabbitVCS did not work for me. Thanks for letting me know about Meld.

Answer (score 7):

To me

> nautilus -q

after installation was enough to show up in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

I am currently using Opensuse 13.1

My problem was that there was no RABBITVCS menu on nautilus.

When starting Nautilus, I discovered that nautilus clomplaims of not having the "python3-simplejson python-simplejson" libraries.

Unfortunately i don't know why the zypper didn't install it when installing rabbitVCS package.

Comment: Where did you see that messag. I did install them with zypper afterwards but still no icons

Comment: I saw it in the systemd-journal, using "journalctl | grep simplejson".

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall rabbitvcs using `sudo apt-get purge rabbitvcs*` and reinstall it using below command lines on Ubuntu.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rabbitvcs/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rabbitvcs-nautilus
nautilus -q
```

and close the already opened window and reopen and right click. You will get RabbitVCS `SVN`, `Git` and `Hg` option on the screen. It's tested on Ubuntu 18.04 and 16.04.

Comment: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.